# Can't get shortcut icon on title tab to show

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, image

I understand and have seen all the tutorials and stack questions about this but for some reason mine is not showing up!! im using ngrok to test this.

My image is in the `assets/images/hello.ico` directory. I dont think im inputting the path right. Im trying to use the `hello.ico` for my tab title.

```html
<head>

<title> ScribeOwl</title>
 <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/images/hello.ico"/>

</head>
```

What is the correct way to fill in the path if my image is in `assets/images` folder? thank you!  Could turbolinks or anything else effect why this isnt working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

are you using erb? try this

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="<%= image_url('hello.ico') %>"/>
```

or just try with favicon_link_tag replacing your line with this

```
<%= favicon_link_tag 'hello.ico' %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<link rel="icon" href="./assets/images/hello.ico?v=2" type="image/x-icon">
```

Comment: Maybe trying putting it into root folder and rename it to "favicon" ? Then it would be "  href="favicon.ico?v=2"  "

Comment: just tried but not working for some reason.. i even downloaded a test .ico on google 16x16

Comment: What does the console in your web browser say? Any errors?

Comment: no errors. However in sublime when i click on the downloaded .ico in the `app/assets/images` folder it says `failed to load`. The image that i used called hello shows up without that error.  I dont think this has to do with the problem tho...

Comment: Out of ideas, but maybe your path to icon has errors. Wait until someone has a better answer than me, because I don't know what's the problem. My every HTML page contains the <link> tag the way I provided to you and everything is working just fine. Except that my .ico is in root folder and href="favicon?v=2" is for the reference.